# log(-X) data transformation instead of log(X+a) when X is negative?

Tags: data-transformation

I'd like to transform my not normally distributed data. Considering all my variables are <0, could I transform my data via `log(-X)` as opposed to `log(X+a)` (`a` being a small positive constant that causes `X+a>0`)?

Taking this thought further, considering my variables are `=<0`, could I use `log(-X+a)`?

Comment: Have you thought about using the inverse hyperbolic sine $\ln \{x+(x^2 + 1)^{1/2} \}$ transformation?

Comment: I haven't. What would be the advantage over `log(-X)` in case `X<0`? Or for what kind of data would that transformation be desirable?

Comment: The ranking woud be preserved. I have also seen the choice of the constant a matter for the results on occasion, depending on what you're doing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You certainly *can* do any of these things.  The question will just be whether/how you can interpret the results.  It's in principle just as legitimate to say "the value of $\log(-X+3)$ is approximately Normal, and differs significantly between groups" vs. "the value of $\log(X)$ is approximately Normal, and differs significantly between groups".

However, what does such a result really mean?

- If you're only comparing discrete groups, then a classical (rank-based) nonparametric test or a permutation test will work about as well as a transformation-based approach.
- If you're doing something more complicated (e.g. with continuous covariates and/or interactions), then you need to justify that "a increase of one unit in $Y$ increases the value of $\log(-X+3)$ by $\beta_1$ units" actually means something ...
- simple transformations such as $\log(X)$ are often interpretable in terms of some mechanism (e.g. the data are log-Normal $\to$ we think that responses are generated by the *product* rather than the sum of many small effects); $\log(X+a)$ is usually (in my experience) just a fudge factor.